# TCP server can only read one message and stops

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I am having some trouble in getting this TCP server run properly... When I connect to it with `netcat`, I can only send one message and then the server does not display the other send messages. When I place `client, addr = tcp_socket.accept()` out of the while loop I can receive multiple messages but can only connect once...

What is the best way to tackles these problems?

**Code**

```
class TCP(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.port = port
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def create_socket(self, port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind(('', port))
        sock.listen(5)
        return sock

    def listen(self, tcp_socket):
        while True:
            client, addr = tcp_socket.accept()
            print "Got connection from", addr
            data = client.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print "TCP", data

    def run(self):
        self.listen(self.create_socket(self.port))
```

Comment: Consider using zmq. It will make your live much simpler. There is even command line tool `zmqc` which allow communication with line oriented messages from console (use my modification which resolves some latest updates: https://github.com/vlcinsky/zmqc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example server application which has `Socket.accept()` outside the loop:

```
class (threading.Thread):
    def listenForClients(self, sock):
        while True:
            client, address = sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(5)
            threading.Thread( target = self.listenToClient, args = (client,address) ).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    response = "Got connection"
                    client.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(5)
        self.listenForClients(sock)
```

this uses a thread for each client because otherwise `Socket.recv()` blocks so clients would have to take turns.